# In extjs,How to insert textfields value into grid on button click

Tags: gridview, extjs

I am implementing project in extjs. i have Option form with its two field as Question and Option. My view code is-

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Question-option',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Question',
        fieldLabel: 'Question',
        allowBlank: false  // requires a non-empty value
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'Option',
        fieldLabel: 'Option',
       allowBlank: false  
    },
    {xtype: 'button', text: 'Ok'}, 
    {xtype: 'button', text: 'Cancel'}
 ]
});
```

Now on add buttonclick, i want to display these inserted field values in gridview. and also want to make option field as blank in order to insert multiple options. and need to display all these inserted options in gridview. So please can you suggest how can i do this. I am very new to extjs,please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shilpa,
There is a an example with a grid and a form that adds a record to the store when you click 'create' button.
i think this represents your scenario closely: 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/writer/writer.html

Comment: Yaa Sir...i want to implement exact view as given in link http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/writer/writer.html. But i want to implement it using MVC architecture and want to use store with localstoragproxy. so not getting how to break this file into model,view,controller and store file. please can you help me...

Comment: Ya i had read MVC architecture guide and also implemented example of email and name displaying using grid. But in that example data it statically added to store and displayed in grid. So thats why i am not getting how to divide this writer.js file into four differnt model,view,controller and store files. So can you please suggest me how i should do it.

Comment: Model goes into Model file, Store goes into Store file, controller ... well you get the idea.

Comment: As per MVC architecture, i had made files as,,,,,,Model code-Ext.define('AM.model.Writer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['Name', 'Email']
});                  Store code-Ext.define('AM.store.Writer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    fields: ['Name', 'Email'],
    
}); 
and remaining all code in view file. Is it Write sir? What should controller file will contain? Actually i am very new to extjs so not getting exact path to follow.